# get class name in decorator python 2.7

Tags: python

How can I get the class of the method that is wrapped by a decorator with Python 2.7?

With this code:

```
def timeit(method):
    def timed(*args, **kw):
        result = method(*args, **kw)

        className = ???
        print '%s.%s'%(className, method.func_name)
        #want printed: Test.run  

        return result

    return timed

class Test(object):
    @timeit 
    def run(self, ):
        print 'run'

a = Test()
a.run()
```

I'm not sure what to put for className = ???.  I want it to print Test.run.

I've seen similar solutions that use im_class and __ self__ but I don't have either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just analyze the `self` argument to the method.

```
def timeit(method):
    def timed(self, *args, **kw):
        result = method(self, *args, **kw)

        className = type(self).__name__
        print '%s.%s'%(className, method.func_name)
        #want printed: Test.run  

        return result

    return timed

class Test(object):
    @timeit 
    def run(self):
        print 'run'

a = Test()
a.run()
```

If it's a `classmethod` then you could use two decorators (ie `@classmethod @timeit`) and get the name via `cls.__name__` (where `cls` is the first argument to `timed` instead of `self`).

If it's a `staticmethod` you will have to turn it into a `classmethod` in order to be able to get a parameter with class info available.